# Как объединить две таблицы в MYSQL в запросе?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Есть таблица genres (на первом скришоте)

[image: Таблица genres]

Также есть таблица genres_posts (второй скриншот)

[image: Таблица genres_posts]

Нужно чтобы при game_id 38 вывелись все жанры из таблицы genres_posts, но при этом имели название из таблицы genres, то есть должно вывести Экшен и Приключения. Я понимаю, что нужно как то объединить запросы с помощью LEFT JOIN, вот только в документации написано в основном по другим примерам и очень сложно понять логику. Поэтому прошу помочь.

Comment: Вы же правильно понимаете, что нужно использовать LEFT JOIN. При этом все примеры, что я встречал, подобны вашему примеру с двумя таблицами, только названия отличаются. Загадочно всё это...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT janr_name FROM genres LEFT JOIN genres_post ON janr_id = genre_id WHERE game_id = 38
```

`LEFT JOIN` объединяет таблицы, а не запросы. `ON` указывает по каким полям данные таблицы нужно соединить.